# Convert 1d array to grayscale bitmap C#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have 1d array which contains the pixel values in range [50,600]. I need to create a bitmap and save image as gray scale.

Below code I tried but my images are blue in color, my expectation in that image should be gray.

```
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(xL, yL, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
            int count = 0;
            for (y = 0; y < xL; y++)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < yL; x++)
                {
                    bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int) arr[count]));
                    count++;
                }
            }
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
```

As the values are not 8 bits so I was not using System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(val,val,val) as it was giving exception "value should be greater than or equal to 0 and less 256".

How can I create gray scale image if my array values lies in range [50,600].

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Protip: don't use `GetPixel`/`SetPixel`, it's incredibly slow. Use `LockBits` instead.

Comment: _"How can I create gray scale image if my array values lies in range [50,600]."_ - you can't, at-least, you can't create a Windows GDI Bitmap to represent that data, because GDI doesn't support greyscale images over 8bpp. You'll need to use OpenGL or Direct3D (i.e. [the `PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale` enum is a lie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474434/set-individual-pixels-in-net-format16bppgrayscale-image))

Comment: ^^ or map those values to fit into 0..255, losing information, of course.

Comment: To clarify: the reason `Format16bppGrayScale` exists is because GDI+ has the ability to _read_ 16bpp files from-disk, however it always processes and displays them as 8bpp, so the enum member exists to allow applications to detect when a 16bpp grayscale file can be read - perhaps to inform users that the file won't be processed nor displayed with correct fidelity.

Comment: @Dai That's not exactly true. The "large" pixel formats `Format16bppGrayScale` and `Format64bppArgb` do work with the bitmap type, but only when used as data container. So you can't use GetPixel/SetPixel, Rotate, Draw, Save and similar functions.

Comment: @PMF can you clarify what you mean by "data container"?

Comment: @Dai: If you use the `Bitmap` class to transfer data around in your application. So if you have your custom reader for 16bpp images, you can use LockBits to fill the bitmap from that data and later display it in your user interface, obviously also using custom display code.

Comment: Actually if you don't mind some minor green colour bias (especially at the low end) you can approximate an 11 bit greyscale image representation by using the intensities of B~1/6, R~1/3 B~1/2 in a 24bit colour BMP of the image and mapping your codes in the range 0 to 2048 onto the dithered colours. Although it can produce slightly annoying artefacts on slowly changing data. It was sometimes used way back to display high dynamic range monochrome images in greyscale on normal PCs.  However, the OP would probably be best served by rescaling his raw data so that the largest value maps to 255.

Comment: You swapped `xL` and `yL` in your `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the color conversion manually. Since you say that the values range from [50...600], I'm assuming your array `arr` is of type `short[]`.

```cs
int value = ((arr[count] - 50) * 255) / 550;
value = Math.Clamp(value, 0, 255);
Color gray = Color.FromArgb(value, value, value);
```

That should give you the gray values you're looking for.

Comment: Fairly sure you need to multiply that by 255, not 256, to get the correct distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a 3rd party library you can use [this one](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) (disclaimer: I'm the author), which is able to handle any [custom pixel formats](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing). And by referencing the [GDI+ specific NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing) you can convert your custom bitmap to regular `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

##### 1. Specify your custom pixel format

Reference [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing#kgysoftdrawingcore-) package and create a type that converts known color types to your custom format. Based on the selected pixel format in your example I assume you have `ushort` values ranging between [50..600]

```cs
internal readonly struct Gray50_600
{
    // The actual underlying value.
    // If my assumption was wrong change it to uint or whatever it actually is.
    private readonly ushort _value;

    internal Gray50_600(Color64 c64)
    {
        Debug.Assert(c64.A == UInt16.MaxValue, "Opaque colors are expected");
        ushort brightness = c64.GetBrightness();

        // Transforming the range from 0..65535 to 50..600
        // while assuming the same sRGB color space as the source has.
        _value = (ushort)(50 + brightness * (550f / 65535f));
    }

    internal Gray50_600(Color32 c32) : this(c32.ToColor64()) { }

    internal Color64 ToColor64() => Color64.FromGray(
        (ushort)((Math.Clamp(_value, 50u, 600u)
            - 50f) * (65535f / 550f)));

    internal Color32 ToColor32() => Color32.FromGray(
        (byte)((Math.Clamp(_value, 50u, 600u)
            - 50f) * (255f / 550f)));
```

##### 2. Interpret your array as a bitmap of your custom gray format

The `BitmapDataFactory` class has a bunch of [`CreateBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/Overload_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_BitmapDataFactory_CreateBitmapData.htm) overloads that allow you to create a bitmap data for a preallocated array, even with a custom pixel format.

Starting with [v8.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing.Core/8.0.0) you are able to specify getter/setter delegates working with wide (64 or 128 bit) colors.

```cs
public IReadWriteBitmapData ToBitmapData(ushort[] buffer, Size size, int stride)
{
    PixelFormatInfo pixelFormat = new PixelFormatInfo
    {
        BitsPerPixel = 16,
        Grayscale = true,
        Prefers64BitColors = true, // may be considered by various operations
    };

    return BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(buffer, size, stride, new CustomBitmapDataConfig
    {
        PixelFormat = pixelFormat,
        BackBufferIndependentPixelAccess = true,
        BackColor = backColor,

        // The getter/setter using Color32
        RowGetColor32 = (row, x) => row.UnsafeGetRefAs<Gray50_600>(x).ToColor32(),
        RowSetColor32 = (row, x, c) => row.UnsafeGetRefAs<Gray50_600>(x) = c.A == Byte.MaxValue
            ? new Gray50_600(c)
            : new Gray50_600(c.ToColor64().Blend(row.BitmapData.BackColor.ToColor64(), row.BitmapData.WorkingColorSpace)),

        // but now you can specify delegates for wide color formats, too:
        RowGetColor64 = (row, x) => row.UnsafeGetRefAs<Gray50_600>(x).ToColor64(),
        RowSetColor64 = (row, x, c) => row.UnsafeGetRefAs<Gray50_600>(x) =
            new Gray50_600(c.A == UInt16.MaxValue ? c
            : c.Blend(row.BitmapData.BackColor.ToColor64(), row.BitmapData.WorkingColorSpace)),
    });
}
```

##### 3. Use your custom bitmap data

As an [`IReadWriteBitmapData`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IReadWriteBitmapData.htm) do whatever you want with your bitmap (see also the Extension Methods part behind the link). To simply use get/set pixels see the examples [here](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_GetReadWriteBitmapData.htm). It's not just you can use essentially the same [`SetPixel`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IWritableBitmapData_SetPixel.htm) as in case of a regular `Bitmap` but it is also much, much faster.

```cs
// The array buffer to use
ushort[] buffer = new ushort[10000];

// Using the method we created above
IReadWriteBitmapData myCustomBitmap = ToBitmapData(buffer, new Size(100, 100),
    stride: 200, backColor: Color.Silver);

// Not just very fast but also does the possibly needed blending with back color
myCustomBitmap.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 128, 64));
```

And if you want to access your pixels as your custom `Gray50_600` structure instead of `Color32`/`Color64` values, you can even do that by the [`ReadRaw<T>`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IReadableBitmapDataRow_ReadRaw__1.htm) and [`WriteRaw<T>`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_IWritableBitmapDataRow_WriteRaw__1.htm) methods:

```cs
// access the custom pixel directly as Gray50_600 at [0,0]:
var myCustomColor = myCustomBitmap[0].ReadRaw<Gray50_600>(0);

// or set directly the value as ushort (allowing even invalid values):
myCustomBitmap[0].WriteRaw<ushort>(0, 55);
```

##### 4. Convert your custom bitmap data to `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

If you use the [GDI+ specific package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing/) you can simply use the [`ToBitmap`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_ReadableBitmapDataExtensions_ToBitmap_1.htm) extension method:

```cs
// Note that you can specify any target pixel format.
// 32 bpp PArgb is the fastest one if you render the bitmap in WinForms, for example.
var bitmap = myCustomBitmap.ToBitmap(PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
```